# How to get Regular Expression in IgGrid cell (Infragistics)?

Tags: javascript, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

how can i have a regular expression on a igTextEditor in igGrid Updating?

i tried to use validate option but it didn't worked.

```
   $("#schedulerTable").igGrid({
            columns: $scope.schedulerColumns,
            width: "87%",
            height: "300px",
            fixedHeaders: true,
            autoGenerateColumns: false,
            autofitLastColumn: true,
            autoCommit: true,
            renderCheckboxes: true,
            responseDataKey: "results",
            dataSource: $scope.schedulerData,
            updateUrl: "",
            primaryKey: 'Id',
            features: [
            {
                name: "Updating",
                generatePrimaryKeyValue: function (evt, ui) {
                    nextPrimarykey -= 1;
                    ui.value = nextPrimarykey;
                },
                enableAddRow: true,
                enableDeleteRow: true,
                editMode: "row",
                columnSettings: [
                   {
                       columnKey: "Id",
                       editorType: "numeric",
                       editorOptions: {
                           readOnly: true
                       }
                   }, {
                       columnKey: "Time",
                       editorType: "text",

                       editorOptions: {
                       },
                       validatorOptions: {
                           regExp: /^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]*\@\w{2,10}\.\w{1,10}$/,
                           onblur: true,
                           onchange: true
                       },

                       required: true,
                       validation: true,
                       defaultValue: "00:00"
                   },
                   {
                       columnKey: "Mo"

                   },
                   {
                       columnKey: "Tu"

                   },
                    {
                        columnKey: "We"

                    },
                    {
                        columnKey: "Th"

                    },
                    {
                        columnKey: "Fi"

                    }]
            }]
        });
```

i want to achive a time picker in the Time Column but that doesn't exist so i try to get only time in the textEditor by regular expression.
the grid gets loaded with columns named Time, Mo- Friday.
if you click on add in grid you can click in the input field and fill your time. the time should get validated before clicking on done and show a error message.

to see how the table look like: https://codepen.io/ablablabla/pen/PJLbJz

Comment: Any html code to understand this alone JS code.

Comment: @headmax if you use the infragistics tool you can create a grid with only calling igGrid on a id of a div. so if you would test this or check it all you have to do is callig $('#whatever').igGrid({}); to get a full working grid.

Comment: for example this https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/QqYZgq

Comment: I just tell you show us your html cos is linked with JS as CSS too. i can create a div class named "schedulerTable" but what should be the others parts ??? a input text for search and ???

Comment: sry i was new to this site . here is the link but i don't know how to reference Ignite but you can see the code which is doing the stuff.https://codepen.io/ablablabla/pen/PJLbJz

Comment: isn't a problem ;), i will adding wait few minutes.

Comment: @i am on but you put mutch directive did you known when you got the error?

Comment: its not an error that happens. check again the site i added a comment. you need to add editing modules for updating feature. i don't get any error it just don't validate the field.

Comment: what i get from your code here https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/PJLbRG

Comment: it's becuase of references. in your first example there is a IgniteUI trial at the buttom right. which shows that its referenced properly but in my example its not. wenn i paseted my grid into your first example it worked. only without editing which is due to modules which you need to use : 
    /infragistics.ui.grid.updating.js,infragistics.ui.grid.shared.js,infragistics.ui.editors.js, example; http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2014.1/ui.iggridupdating

Comment: it should look like this https://codepen.io/ablablabla/pen/PJLbJz

Comment: https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/PJLbRG

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/IgniteUI/help-samples/tree/master/17.1/EN/grid/editing-api-events/fiddle shouw be like this but instead of first name input field imagine a text editor where you can only but time like 13:45 or so. and if its not time just show a notification.

Comment: i got it too, but what zone should for your regex?? wich pattern?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157126/discussion-between-headmax-and-amsel).

Comment: https://codepen.io/ablablabla/pen/PJLbJz got it now. idk the pattern just try the one for mail for now i can change that later.

Comment: so codepen.io jsfiddle.com solve the problem ;) lol, good done, gl for the next so.

Comment: yes but still the problem isn't the grid its validating in the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lack of validation is because the [`validatorOptions`](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2017.1/ui.igtexteditor#options:validatorOptions) belong to the [`editorOptions`](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2017.1/ui.iggridupdating#options:columnSettings.editorOptions) (as those get passed down to whatever editor you choose as provider). The `validation: true` only gets some defaults, which really won't do much for a text field besides the required.

And then the RegExp option (which is for an email in the snippet above as far as I can tell) has been [`pattern`](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2017.1/ui.igvalidator#options:pattern) since 15.2 :) So in the end for that time column you can try:

```
//...
    editorOptions: {
     validatorOptions: {
       pattern: /^\d{1,2}\:\d{2}$/,
       onblur: true,
       onchange: true
     },
    },
//..
```

Here's an updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrgYxj

Edit: Or if you want to set the error message:

```
//...
    editorOptions: {
     validatorOptions: {
       pattern: {
        expression: /^\d{1,2}\:\d{2}$/,
        errorMessage: "Time should match a pattern like 00:00"
       },
       onblur: true,
       onchange: true
     },
    },
//..
```

Depending on your goals you could also use a [Mask Editor](https://www.igniteui.com/editors/mask-editor-basic) or a [Date Editor](https://www.igniteui.com/editors/date-editor) as provider. Also the obligatory docs link: https://www.igniteui.com/help/iggrid-updating

P.S. Bind to an empty array to avoid the error for that first row that has no values and more importantly primary key.

Comment: how can i change the notification if it doesn't match the pattern? thanks for your good solution.

Comment: @Amsel You can either set a global `errorMessage` or provide one for the pattern check. I've added a snippet for the latter to the answer.